# wxWidgets Title bar icon

Tags: icons, wxwidgets

I want to change the default icon that shows up at the top left corner of the frame.
I have tried many approaches- xpm, ico, bmp,
using `SetIcon(wxIcon(wxT("icon.xpm")));` as suggested [here.](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/firstprograms/)
I tried different icon sizes, 16x16, 24x24 and 32x32.
I've also tried adding `MYICON1 ICON "Logo.ico"` in the resource.rc file, `#define MYICON1 101` in the resource.h file and `SetIcon(wxIcon(MYICON1));` to the frame constructor.. 

btw, i'm using wxwidgets 2.8 on visual studio 2010

EDIT:

> I've also tried adding `MYICON1   ICON "Logo.ico"` in the resource.rc file, `#define MYICON1 101` in the resource.h file and `SetIcon(wxIcon(MYICON1));` to the frame constructor..

With this approach, I get an error in the wxIcon(int) constructor..

> 1>xsframe.cpp(17): error C2248: 'wxString::wxString' : cannot access private member declared in class 'wxString' 
>   1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\wx/string.h(682) : see declaration of 'wxString::wxString' 
>   1> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\wx/string.h(659) : see declaration of 'wxString'

PS, xsframe is my main frame. whose icon i'm trying to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quoting Vaclav's answer from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/wx-users/app$20icon/wx-users/WAjn22X9Dvo/ZEFXMNckrawJ):

> You can set your main frame's icon with wxFrame::SetIcon. Application
>   icon can be changed by adding a new icon resource to your .rc file:
>
> ```
> appicon ICON "myapp.ico"
> #include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
> ```
>
> Note that this icon must be the first icon in your .rc file *and* it
>   must be the first one when you sort your icons alphabetically. This is
>   because MS developers weren't able to make their mind on how to
>   determine app's icon: it is the first one in .rc file under Windows 9x
>   and the alphabetically first one under NT (or vice versa).

Most people usually miss this. Hope that fixes things.

Answer (score 4):

SetIcon(wxICON(MYICON1));

in file gdicmn.h ,line 166

```
/* Useful macro for creating icons portably, for example:

    wxIcon *icon = new wxICON(sample);

  expands into:

    wxIcon *icon = new wxIcon("sample");      // On Windows
    wxIcon *icon = new wxIcon(sample_xpm);    // On wxGTK/Linux
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:  MYICON1 ICON "Logo.ico" in the resource.rc file, and SetIcon(wxIcon(MYICON1)); to the frame constructor

That is the approach I use.

There is an extra step you need to do.  In the resource.h file you need to define MYICON1  Something like this:

```
#define MYICON1  101
```

You have to ensure that the icon file contain ALL the required resolutions - I always ensure it has 16by16, 32by32 AND 256by256  The more the merrier!

It is a good idea if the application icon is the FIRST icon in the resource file.

I recommend upgrading to wxWidgets v2.9.4 - lots of things start working better.

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention that.. i have actually defined `MYICON1` in the resource.h file.
I get an error in the seticon function, in the wxIcon() constructor..
`1>xsframe.cpp(17): error C2248: 'wxString::wxString' : cannot access private member declared in class 'wxString'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\wx/string.h(682) : see declaration of 'wxString::wxString'
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\wx/string.h(659) : see declaration of 'wxString'`

Comment: So, what happens at line 17?  Please post details without having to be asked at each step of the way.

Comment: at line 17 there's `SetIcon(wxIcon(MYICON1));`
also i tried using logo.ico with other sizes, 16x16, 32x32, and 256x256. but clearly, the problem is at the wxIcon(int) constructor call.
I checked the header file, and `wxString(int);` is in the private section. so how does one access it?

Comment: Are you including all the icon sizes in the same ico file?

Comment: yes. 3 icons in same ico file.. but the problem isn't there.
i don't understand why wxString(int) is being called. shouldn't there be an int overloaded constructor for wxIcon??

Comment: The string error happens because it sees MYICON1 as the integer from resource.h and hance the implicit conversion of int to string is prohibited. This can be solved by using wxICON() // Notice the upper case of ICON . This wxICON is a macro

Answer (score 1):

Use the string name of the icon, not the numeric identifier. Look at any wxWidgets sample for an example.

Comment: you mean `SetIcon(wxIcon(wxT("icon.xpm")));` right?
i tried that.. didn't help... no errors but the icon is the same default..
and i don't know if it's necessary but i also wxInitializedAllImageHandlers() before calling set icon.. didn't help..
does it have anything to do with me running it on windows 8?

Comment: `SetIcon()` works fine under Windows 8. OTOH "icon.xpm" is not a valid icon name. If you use XPMs, you must use the name of the icon itself to wxIcon ctor, e.g. `icon_xpm` (look inside your `icon.xpm` file to be sure). But for the application icon you'll almost always use an `.ico` because it needs to be in your resources in ICO format anyhow. In this case you have "foo ICON foo.ico" in the `.rc` file and you should use `wxIcon("foo")` in the code.

Comment: i tried. and it didn't work either. in my `.rc` file i have `MYICON ICON "Logo2.ico"` 
and in my frame constructor, `SetIcon(wxIcon(_("MYICON1")));`
however, the `.exe` in the release folder does show the icon(explorer file icon). and it remains there even when i remove the seticon(). it seems just the presence of the icon in the `.rc` file sets the application icon.. so what do i do about the titlebar icon?

Comment: You're now speaking about a completely different icon... Please make up your mind. Also, using "MYICON" in the resources and "MYICON1" in your code doesn't help. You're confused because you're trying to do too many things at once, calm down, check everything once again and it will work.

Comment: sorry about that..
i removed everything and started over..
first i added the icon in the resource file (opened resource.rc in resource view > right click > add resource > icon > import > select logo.ico > open) Btw, logo.ico has 3 icons, 16x16, 32x32 and 256x256. This added `IDI_ICON1 ICON "logo.ico"` in my `resource.rc` file and `#define IDI_ICON1 106` in my `resource.h` file.
next I opened my frame constructor, added `#include "resource.h"` to that page, and later, `SetIcon(wxIcon(_("IDI_ICON1")));` to the constructor, right before `Centre();`
where am i going wrong?

Comment: [Here's](http://txtup.co/CgvVF) my complete `resource.rc` file.  

And [Here's](http://txtup.co/pF8mL) the `resource.h` file.

Comment: Your icon has actually the ID "#106" and not "IDI_ICON1". The built in resource editor uses numeric IDs and then defines C++ identifiers to correspond to them but they're not real icon IDs. Again, just have a look at `sample.rc` file included in wxWidgets and used by all the samples for the simplest way to make it work, without bothering with numeric IDs at all.

Comment: thank you so much it worked.. :)
also i got it working using xpm (fairly simple, `#include "logo.xpm"` then `wxicon(logo_xpm)`), but ico is much much better. (alpha channel and all)

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty, non-portable, only-Windows solution (worked for me in Windows 7, wxWidgets 3.0.4, vc110):

```
#ifdef __WXMSW__
#include "wx/msw/private.h" //for wxGetInstance()
#endif
...

//in Frame's constructor:
HWND hWnd = this->GetHandle();
HINSTANCE hInstance = wxGetInstance();

HICON hIcon = ExtractIcon(hInstance, L"someicon.ico", 0);
SetClassLongPtr(hWnd, GCLP_HICONSM, (LONG_PTR)hIcon);
```

Could be useful for doing some other tricks on the window?