# wxWidgets not showing app icon on windows platform

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, windows-10, wxwidgets

I am struggling to change the app icon on windows platform using wxWidgets 3.1.4 as ui framework and C++ as language, I tried to compile with msvc (VS2019) and gcc , the app works fine, no error messages but no app icon, I searched the documentation but no solution, even I tried to compile and run demo apps included with wxWidgets and I had the same issue.

I am using widows 10, wxWidgets 3.1.4, msvc latest, gcc 10.2.

if you require more information, please comment, I did not include code snippet because I tested it with several demos on the net including the ones coming with wxWidgets and still the same problem.

here is some code upon request, this code is extracted from the demo called bombs included with wxWidgets:

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Name:        bombs.cpp
// Purpose:     Bombs game
// Author:      P. Foggia 1996
// Modified by: Wlodzimierz Skiba (ABX) since 2003
// Created:     1996
// Copyright:   (c) 1996 P. Foggia
// Licence:     wxWindows licence
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifndef  WX_PRECOMP
#   include "wx/wx.h"
#endif //precompiled headers


#include "bombs.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

#ifndef wxHAS_IMAGES_IN_RESOURCES
#   include "bombs.xpm"
#endif

wxIMPLEMENT_APP(BombsApp);

// Called to initialize the program
bool BombsApp::OnInit()
{
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    m_frame = new BombsFrame(&m_game);

    m_frame->NewGame(bombsID_EASY, false);

    return true;
}


BombsFrame::BombsFrame(BombsGame *game)
    : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, wxT("wxBombs"), wxDefaultPosition,
        wxSize(300, 300), wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE|wxMINIMIZE_BOX)
{
    m_game = game;
    m_easyCorner = false;
    m_lastLevel = bombsID_EASY;

    SetIcon(wxICON(bombs));

#if wxUSE_STATUSBAR
    CreateStatusBar();
#endif

    
    // Ensure the subwindows get resized o.k.
    //  OnSize(width, height);

    // Centre frame on the screen.
    Centre(wxBOTH);

    // Show the frame.
    Show();
}
```

Comment: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=13983 https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=45255 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188724/wxwidgets-title-bar-icon https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=45255 Top four Google results for me searching 'wxwidgets app icon'

Comment: Also, include code. No one magically knows your project and what might need changing.

Comment: @Hzine, are you trying to add the icon in the resource file? Or you are reading it directly from the disk? can you modify the `minimal` sample accordingly?

Comment: @sweenish, I used that example the first, sadly not working for me, I may have some trouble with compatibility with windows, I am not sure but I have doubt, I included code upon your request, the full code projects can be found on https://www.wxwidgets.org/

Comment: @Igor, I tried all what I could found of ways, even here in stackoverflow, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097585/how-to-change-icon-in-exe-app-wxwidgets-with-c, I tested some accepted answers but no way, I think I am missing some settings, but I don't know where!

Comment: @Hzine, ok, so you set it up in the code and through the resources. if this is the code you are using - try to step inside the `wxICON` constructor and see where does it fail. Maybe you icon is not really an icon? Or an unsupported ico format? Can you upload you icon somewhere?

Comment: @Igor, actually I checked on that, and I tried a whole structure of a program from wxWigets demos, that contains it own icon and resource file, so at this point I can say I am sure that all is set correctly, I am currently installing Linux on VM to see if the problem is related to my windows-10 or to the build of wxWidgets that I have.

Comment: @Hzine, for the test - can you rename your icon file to be `bombs.ico` and try it to recompile and run? Also, when you tried to debug it - what happened? Are you able to successfully load the file in the `wxICON` constructor?